# Remove all characters from a string from last comma onwards

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a string that looks like this:

```
'Welcome, your bed is made, your tea is ready.'
```

Using jquery, how can I remove all the characters after the the last comma including the last comma itself so that the string shows as:

```
'Welcome, your bed is made' // all characters after last comma are removed
```

Comment: Yea, you don't need jQuery to do string manipulation.

Comment: For some reason my working answer ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26464445/1317805)) has been downvoted. I'm mentioning this here in case you look at it and think it doesn't work because of the downvote - as the code snippet proves, it works fine. This seems to just be a random downvote for no particular reason related to the answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply read until the last `,`:

```
str = str.substr(0, str.lastIndexOf(","));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can using combination of `.split()` and `.slice()`

```js
var str = 'Welcome, your bed is made, your tea is ready.';
var arr = str.split(',');
arr = arr.splice(0, arr.length - 1)
alert(arr.join(','))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string's `replace()` method with the following regular expression:

```js
var str = 'Welcome, your bed is made, your tea is ready.'

str = str.replace(/,([^,]*)$/, '');

$('#result').text(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? If you run the code snippet this works perfectly...

Comment: Basically, this: http://jsperf.com/regex-vs-lastindexof-1
Don't use regexes for simple string manipulations.

Comment: @Cerbrus unless you're running a game at 60fps, the difference here is negligible.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't mean we should teach users to use regexes for everything.

Comment: I used it in a php like: $linkvar = 'href="'.esc_attr(preg_replace('/.([^.]*)$/', '.svg', $img)).'" And it did the job for me very well. So what is wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var str = 'Welcome, your bed is made, your tea is ready.';
    var n = str.lastIndexOf(",");
    var str1 = str.slice(0,n);
});
```

Comment: str1 has your final string.